# Firebase realtime database: load & monitor children (Swift) - best practice?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

This seems like it ought to have a very simple answer.

I am building an app using SwiftUI and firebase realtime database.
The database will have a node called `items` with a large number of children - on the order of 1,000.
I'd like the app to load the contents of that node children when it launches, then listen to firebase for future additions of children. Imagine the following:

```
struct Item { … }   // some struct
var items: [Item] = []
let itemsRef = Database.database().reference().child("items")
```

According to firebase, this call ought to load in all the children one at a time, and then add new ones as they are added to the `items` node in firebase:

```
itemsRef.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
   // add a single child based on snapshot
   items.append(Item(fromDict: snapshot.value as! [String:String])
}
```

That gets the job done, but seems hugely inefficient compared to using the `getData()` method they supply, which hands us a dictionary containing *all* the children:

```
itemsRef.getData() { error, snapshot in
   // set all children at once base on snapshot
   items = Item.itemArray(fromMetaDict: snapshot.value as! [String:[String:String]])
}
```

It would seem best to use `getData()` initially, then `observe(.childAdded)` to monitor additions. But then how do we prevent the `observe` completion block from running 1,000 times when it fires up? The [firebase docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data) say that that's what will happen:

> This event is triggered once for each existing child and then again every time a new child is added to the specified path.

Thanks in advance!

PS I didn't think it necessary to include definitions for the functions `Item.init(fromDict:)` or `Item.itemArray(fromMetaDict:)` — hopefully it's clear what they are meant to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is (or: should be) no difference between listening for `.childAdded` on a path versus listening for `.value` or calling `getData() on that same path. The distinction is purely client-side and the wire traffic is (or: should be) the same.

It is in fact quite common to listen for `.child*` events to manipulate some data structure/UI, and then also listen for the `.value` event to commit those changes, as `.value` is guaranteed to fire *after* all corresponding `.child*`.

---

A common trick to do the first big batch of data in `.value` or `getData()`, and then use `.child*` for granular updates is to have a boolean flag to indicate whether you got the initial data already, and set if to `false` initially.

In the `.child*` handlers, only process the data if the flag is true.

```
itemsRef.observe(.childAdded) { snapshot in
   if isInitialDataProcessed {
       items.append(Item(fromDict: snapshot.value as! [String:String])
    }
}
```

And then in your `.value`/`getData` handler, process the data and then set the flag to true.

Comment: Thank you, Frank! That's very helpful. I wouldn't have thought of the "common trick" because of the cost of a thousand unneeded calls to the .childAdded handler… but it sounds like that is super quick if a guard statement in each causes an immediate return. I'll go with that!

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph is interesting too—about committing on the .value callback because it's guaranteed to happen after the corresponding .child* events. Is there anywhere I can go to learn tips like this? All I've been working from are the docs I linked to above.

Comment: The calls are all local, after the network traffic for the entire path is in already, so it's pretty quick. --- I'm not sure if we still document that the `.value` event comes last, but it definitely does and lots of devs depends on that, so it's unlikely to ever (intentionally/permanently) change.

Comment: I accidentally found it stated in the docs - not in a place that I would have thought to look, but very useful. https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/retrieve-data#section-event-guarantees

Comment: Also, somewhat related: I've been finding that my .childChanged observers fire for .childAdded events as well. Is that to be expected? I could find documentation about it one way or the other, but I had assumed they wouldn't.

Comment: YES! It looks like the Admin SDK documentation is closer to the original docs for this, where the guarantee was indeed stated. Good to hear you found it.  --- I don't think there's any defined order to the `child` events, since they are mutually exclusive.

Comment: I guess I didn't express it clearly. I've noticed that my .childChanged observers have been firing when a child is added to the node that they're observing. I thought they only were supposed to fire for changes to existing children, not when new children are added.

Comment: That's a different problem, so not ideal deep down in comments, but I expect you're adding a property *under* an existing child so the the child itself changes. The `child_` applies to the nodes directly under the path you listen to.